# Chrome is truncating part of my pdf address

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, truncate

We have a catalog on our college website.
It may be found here:
https://www.southark.edu/admissions/resources/course-catalog

The links going down the left side of the page point to specific pages within the catalog.
For example:
https://www.southark.edu/images/catalogs/2021-2022/2021-2022_SouthArk_Catalog_FINAL.pdf#page=100

But when clicked, Chrome truncates the last portion of the url (in this case, #page=100), and it displays the first page of the catalog, not the intended page.

This happens in Chrome, but not Firefox.

It has worked in Chrome for years, but now it does not.

Any idea why Chrome is doing this and what kind of workaround I might be able to do?

P.S. I just tested it in Safari on my iPhone and it is doing it on there as well.

Thanks,
Charley

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that it is due to the Chrome PDF extension.  If I turn it off, it operates as it should.